# Can apps track visitors to your WhatsApp profile?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, privacy

There are apps called "WhatsApp Tracker" or "Whats Tracker" that claim to display new visitors to my WhatsApp profile.

[image]

I tried those apps and turned out the apps didn't do what they claim. I am not sure about the logic behind the design for it to accomplish this function.

In my humble opinion, it is not possible with the current WhatsApp infrastructure to track down visitors who have been specifically seeing your WhatsApp profile (for example: looking at a display picture, watching status updates)

Is this really possible? Is the above-mentioned app genuine? I did not find it so... But if it is even scarcely, then what logic helps to track down visitors?

Comment: Even if WhatsApp (owned by Facebook) have this mechanism to harvest information, you can be sure that it will not be exposed for others to use. That app and another app which claims this capability appear to be fakes and installing such apps is rather a risk

Comment: just as I remarked in the question...yep.. those are fake apps that claim to track but do nothing except track your private information... and sell it to ad agencies.

Comment: Whats Tracker is false. it doesn't do what it says. its not even in real time